# can't show result of two columns in blade, laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to show columns of two tables in my template, but I have not been successful

Template :

```
@foreach ($LatestSeeker_list_adv as $ads)
    <span>ads id</span><span>{{ $ads->advertise->id }}</span>
    <span>inf id</span><span>{{ $ads->information->id }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Controller :

```
public function SeekerLatest()
{
    $LatestSeeker_list = Advertise_Model::with('information')->get();

    return view('Users.Seeker.LatestAds.index',compact('LatestSeeker_list'));
}
```

Advertise Model :

```
public function Information()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Information_Model');
    }
```

Information Model :

```
public function Advertise()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Advertise_Model');
    }
```

advertise migration :

```
Schema::table('advertise', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('information_id')->references('id')->on('information');
        });
```

error :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'information.advertise__model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *
>   from `information` where `information`.`advertise__model_id` in (1,
>   2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the relationship columns so that laravel knows what rows it needs to to select to display the relationship.

```
public function Information()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Information_Model', 'id', 'information_id');
}
```

See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one for more information